# Does any other UTF-8-encoded code point use the ESC byte 0x1B?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Is there any Unicode codepoint that one of the bytes in its utf-8 representation is the ESC byte (0x1B), not including the 0x1B codepoint itself?

Context: The ESC byte is used in [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (in terminals) and I'd like to know whether that byte can appear as part of a utf-8 byte sequence.

Comment: Note: you use the term "ANSI escape code", which are really CSI codes (so 0x9B, or in UTF-8: 0xC2 0x9B). The old 8-bit to 7-bit is done with ESC sequences, so `ESC [` is the way to send 0x9B with 7-bit terminals). Note: most terminals will not interpret the \u009B as `ESC [`, and so as terminal command, but there will be exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all bytes in a UTF-8 multi-byte sequence have bit 7 set.  Only the single-byte ASCII range 0-127 has bit 7 clear, and that includes byte `0x1B` (whose bit pattern is `00011011`), so no other encoded codepoint will have a `0x1B` byte in it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

| First code point | Last code point | Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 | Code points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+0000 | U+007F | 0xxxxxxx |  |  |  | 128 |
| U+0080 | U+07FF | 110xxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |  | 1920 |
| U+0800 | U+FFFF | 1110xxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  | 61440 |
| U+10000 | U+10FFFF | 11110xxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 1048576 |